# Deploying to gh-pages with React doesn't render components?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have an app which I'm deploying to gh-pages with `npm gh-pages` package

I do this command `"deploy": "npm run build && gh-pages -d build"` it creates build folder normally.
  But when I go to gh-pages it is rendering only one static component. You can see [here](https://kiraburova.github.io/Marvel-ReactJS-API/)

In networks I can see that resources are loading up, js files, css files.
I'm not sure what the problem is. Can it be because I'm using react router?

All the help will be much appreciated.

Full code can be found here [link](https://github.com/KiraBurova/Marvel-ReactJS-API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are hosting your React App in a subdirectory, which means that your route "/" is not valid here anymore.

Add the homepage property in your package.json file.

```
"homepage": "https://kiraburova.github.io/Marvel-ReactJS-API/",
```

Comment: For whaterever reason It shows me my static component and doesn't show Routes

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I just tried to deploy again, clear cache and wait and it seems to be working